# Generate files from Ansible templates without executing plays?

Tags: ansible, ansible-template

I'm trying to construct an Ansible template file for my playbook and it takes a certain amount of trial-and-error to figure out the correct template variables the template (.j2) file requires.  Is there any way to run Ansible so that it will generate files from templates without actually executing the tasks in the playbook?  I just want to see the file that will be created from the template but not run the plays themselves until I know my template is correct.

Comment: What do you mean "without executing tasks"? If templates use variables, they need those values, if they come from previous tasks, those need to be executed. And you can always run Ansible with `--check` and `--diff`.

Comment: You made a good point.  I think using diff and check together will accomplish what I'm trying to do.  Thanks.  BTW, if you want to write that as an answer, I'll give you credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Templates are generally used to generate files based on either host facts, variables, or the results of some previous tasks, so it's generally natural to run them along the tasks (at least after gathering the facts).

When developing an Ansible playbook with templates, you can always perform a ["dry run"](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_checkmode.html).

Run `ansible-playbook` with `--check --diff` options to get feedback on tasks without actually running them.

Also you can use `backup` parameter for `template` tasks which will preserve the previous versions of the file instead of overwriting them (you can add `backup: {{ keep_backups }}` to all tasks and use `keep_backups` as a "global" switch.